# Firestore paginate document fields

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first time using Firestore. The project is written in Python. I've a collection let's say posts and then a document for each user that contains an array of his posts. Is there a way to paginate that array?

to get a document

```
docoument = collection.document(
    str(document_id)
).get()
```

doing `document.to_dict()` will load the entire document to memory which can have thousands and maybe millions of data

What's a proper solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you read a document in Firestore with the client SDK, you are downloading the entire document containing all fields. While you can definitely paginate the data in the array, I can tell you that I cannot see any reason why you implement pagination. That's because you already have the **entire** document in memory. You should implement pagination when you read multiple documents from a collection or a query. Loading data in smaller chunks is called pagination.

> Doing `document.to_dict()` will load the entire document to memory which can have thousands and maybe millions of data

A document cannot hold millions of data, because each document in a collection is [limited to 1 MiB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas). So there is no way you can get over this limitation.

Comment: Hey Mohamed. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?